# How to type annotate object merging like rest operator does in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, merge, typescript-generics

I have this function which merge arbitrary numbers of objects

```js
function merge(...objs) {
  return objs.reduce((res, cur) => {
    for (const key in cur) {
      res[key] = cur[key]
    }
    return res;
  }, {});
}
```

at first I thought this function could not be type annotated, but then I tried rest parameter which is quite similar to my `merge` function

```js
const obj = {
  ...{ name: { ownName: 'Lewis' } },
  ...{ link: 'google.com' }
}
type Obj = typeof obj // I can happily get the Obj type
```

Then I came across this idea: when u don't know the types in advance, use generic. But how can I define rest generic types like
`function merge<T, U, V...>(...objs: Array<T | U | V...>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to infer `rest` arguments is using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

function merge<T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>,
    Objs extends T[]
>(...objs: [...Objs]):UnionToIntersection<Objs[number]>
function merge<T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>,
    Objs extends T[]
>(...objs: [...Objs]) {
    return objs.reduce((acc, obj) => ({
        ...acc,
        ...obj
    }), {});
}

const result = merge({ a: 1 }, { b: 2 })
result.a // ok
result.b // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/PTAEGMCcFMBMEsAuBnUBzA9tViOgBaKIAOyAXCMogIbgDWGAbtJAGYA2GA7gHTgYBbYNWABWAAwBmAOyiATAA4AbAChEAT2LRQAVQB28DHoAqGAJJ7ELZNHCJDegDw6AfKAC8oABQ7Q0AB5WerCo1HrqoAD83nRkugCUHm6MGPCwoHF60MyQiQFBId4qoCWgsaDweqwsoGYqie7JqbDFpdF1pRmgWTkA3CoqrACuenYOoAIsaNCOxn6B0MGoAEq2GJCwjgAKkBhakBoA0tDqADSgI3R63Houp60lAPIARgBWqPmLhcYA2gC6KhcXh4IIwb3IoB%20IJ4L3ef3iZH0DlMFiskBsYyMjlhyB%20eiGAmeLD%20LkGI0xegmUxmc0%20S1Aq34G22u32RxO50u1y4t3unRx8wKqF%20AKB0LB7ziUJBOPhoAA3g9QDBEENIJSJcgeDBYENwNAvF5aOBzhKGm4vIrOp1oca%20daSuK3kqAL7xc7yt39F0Dfh6KjK7BDdiIDxUyDTS2gahxACMoBdHtAzzicgT8RUMGQwcQPGooBAoAwdEzQZDPGeBbAxaAA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments), in my blog, you can find more infering techniques.

As for the return type.

`Objs[number]` - infered as a union of all elements in the array
`UnionToIntersection` - takes the union and merges it.

P.S. try to avoid mutations in typescript. [Here](https://catchts.com/mutations) you can find an information how to deal with them

Comment: What a nifty technique, but I can't understand why there are two function declarations, if I delete the upper one, TS will yell at me. I only use multiple function declarations under function overloading.

Comment: The upper function is an overload of bottom. Docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: my answer was way better than this one, but I have guess

Comment: @captain-yossarian yeah I know it's overloading, but I can't figure out why bother overloading if only having one function declaration

Comment: @crazyones110 you can get rid of overloading and just use type assertion at the end `UnionToIntersection<Objs[number]>`. Personally , I prefer to overload my function instead of assertion. I think it safer because overloads are bivariant to function declaration. It is up to you